# SQL Injection on update query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-injection, code-injection

So I have a server set up to serve payment requests. A user enters their credit card details in a form.

Query to inject here:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET credit_card'".$credit_card."', cvv='".$cvv."', expdate='".$exp."' WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
```

I am trying to change another users password from this query.

Where the `$credit_card` is posted from a form. Im trying to inject the `$credit_card` part by writing my own query and getting rid of the rest by adding `;--` to the end.

The statement I am using for `$credit_card` is :

```
', password='test' where userid='10';--
```

Now, I am positive this was working yesterday but now the following error appears and I cannot wrap my head around it. Any help please?

> Query failed: UPDATE users SET credit_card'', password='test' WHERE userid='20';--, cvv='', expdate='' WHERE userid='20'

Comment: Notice that the error message show the text of condition: `where userid='20'` **twice** -- I think there is a problem when you are building the sql string.

Comment: Yes but isnt the ;-- supposed to ignore the rest of the string after it? So it shoudlnt matter what is after it. And also the first userid should be different as I want to change another users password. The image is jsut a test

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not all database functions accept multiple statements so the `;` delimiter may be considered unexpected input.
2. The syntax for single-line comments in MySQL is `-- Foo` (please note the white space after the double-dash).
3. If the server code is yours, you can just print the actually error message generated by the server (and not some generic "something went wrong" text). If it isn't, just copy and paste the SQL code from the error message into your favourite MySQL client.